# Abelianization and Centralizer of group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $g \in G$. Prove that $|C_G(g)| \geq |Ab(G)|$, where $C_G(g)$ is centralizer for $g\in G$ and $Ab(G)$ is abelianization of group G.

I manage to prove that $|C_G(g)| > |Z(G)|$ and I know that $Ab(G) = G/G'$ and $C_G(g) \unlhd N_G(g)$. But I have no idea how to show this in question. Anyone can help?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C125.5790).  Please read the post linked here, and return to improve this post.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven yeah, I mean $\geq$, but its obious when equality holds

Answer (score 3):

Hint: a conjugacy class $Cl_G(x)$ can be mapped injectively into $G’$. What would be the map?

Comment: Maybe something like this $F(gxg^{-1}) = [g,x]$?

Comment: Yes so what does that tell you?

Comment: $|Cl_G(x)| \leq |G'|$ and that implies $|C_G(g)| \geq |Ab(G)|$ because |Cl_G(x)| = [G : C_G(x)]?

Comment: Almost there: try to prove that $|Cl_G(x)|=|G:C_G(x)|$.

Comment: The least follows because there is isomorphism $F: Cl_G (x) \rightarrow G/C_G (x)$ such that $F(gxg^{-1}) = g C_G (x)$.

Comment: Correct, the cosets (be careful with the mod out notation, only for normal subgroups) are in 1-1 correspondence with the members of the conjugacy class. It is not an isomorphism though again you need a bijective Correct, the cosets (be careful with the mod out notation, only for normal subgroups) are in 1-1 correspondence with the members of the conjugacy class. It is not an isomorphism though. Again, you need a bijective map. So, well done!

Comment: Final remark, if you know the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem: $G$ acts on itself by conjugation, the orbits are the conjugacy classes, the stabilizers are the centralizers.